# No puedo leer un dato dentro de un array dentro de una funcion

Tags: javascript, nodejs, api, express

estoy estancada hace un tiempo con un tarea que tengo que hacer. El objetivo era hacer una api rest con un enpoint para objeter datos y otro para postearlos. Hasta aqui bien, todo funciona, pero ahora debo ponerle una condicion a ese post, que depende de mi funcion get.
Si el "total" es mayor al req.body.amount debo poder postear sino, no.
Lo que hice fue crear un array vacio, y pushear alli dentro mi total, pero cuando lo quiero utilizar en la funcion post, no lee nada..esta vacio. Tengo idea de como seguir trabajandolo, por eso el post esta inconcluso, pero no puedo avanzar si no tengo mi array total.
que estoy haciendo mal? Muchas Gracias por su tiempo! 
(se aceptan otras sugerencias ;) )

Este es mi código:
Aqui obtengo los datos de mongo y calculo el total, que pusheo dentro de mi array.

```
var todo = []

function getTransactions(req, res, next){
    Transaction.find()
    .then(resolve => {
        res.send(resolve)
        const a = resolve
        const total = a.map(function(element){
            return element.aumount
        })
        .reduce(function(prev, element, index, sum){
            return prev + element
        }, 0)
        todo.push(total)
        console.log('total', todo) // <-- funciona ok.
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.log('Se produjo un error', error)
    })
}

function postDebit(req, res, next){
    const transaction =  new Transaction({
       type: req.body.type,
        aumount: req.body.aumount,
        effectiveDate : new Date()
    })
    console.log('total', todo.length) <-- devuelve []
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes probar haciendo esto

```
var todo = []

function getTransactions(req, res, next){
    Transaction.find()
    .then(resolve => {
            const a = resolve
            const total = a.map(function(element){
                return element.aumount
            })
            .reduce(function(prev, element, index, sum){
                return prev + element
            }, 0)
            todo.push(total)
            console.log('total', todo) // <-- funciona ok.
            // primero llenar el arreglo y después hacer la respuesta
            res.send(resolve)

    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.log('Se produjo un error', error)
    })
}

function postDebit(req, res, next){
    const transaction =  new Transaction({
       type: req.body.type,
        aumount: req.body.aumount,
        effectiveDate : new Date()
    })
    console.log('total', todo.length) <-- devuelve []
}
```